# `Class::Class() : a(0), b(1)` meaning

Tags: c++

What does the following mean? I don't know what to search for as just searching `:` gives me nothing...

```
Server::Server(int port) : listen_sock(0), current_autogen_nickname(1)
```

where `listen_sock` used later in:

```
listen_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

and `current_autogen_nickname` not used.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list is the answer

Comment: Great minds think alike

Comment: yes you can search for it: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+does+colon+in+constructor+mean , https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%2B%2B%20what%20does%20colon%20in%20constructor%20mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you are defining a constructor for class Server which is declared with one int parameter. The class has fields listen_sock which is being set to 0 and then current_autogen_nickname which is being set to 1

You are basically defining a constructor and using an initializer list.

Comment: Then, why bother initializing `listen_sock` even if it will be assigned later?

Comment: Better to give everything a value when constructing. As code is organic best to get the initialisation list to do this at the start

Comment: Plus one to what Ed Heal said. You don't have to do it. Just good practice.

Comment: Also put the initialisation list in the same order as they are declared

Comment: @JohnsonSteward because someone writes bad code. It should have been initialized to the actual socket descriptor right in that initializer list, and should have thrown an exception if the socket call failed.